# Changing background colour of a Manipulate element

Tags: manipulate, color

Please consider the following:

```
 Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 2}];
```

Now, I would like to change the background colour to yellow. I tried the following, but in this case the nice looking rounded corners of the manipulate element get lost:

```
Panel[#, Background -> Yellow] &@
 Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 2}, 
  Paneled -> False]
```

Maybe somebody has a better idea.

**EDIT**

The background colour of `Manipulate`is by default grey.
[image: <code>Manipulate</code>]

In addition the graphical element in which the `Manipulate` is embedded has rounded corners
[image: rounded corner] which I would like to keep. Applying my approach will change the colour but I loose the rounded corners.

Comment: What rounded corners? Please include an image of your desired result

Comment: Panel[] (and thus Manupulate[] too) in Windows 7 does not have round corners. It is kind of system dependent.

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi Good advice, because I intend to deploy my notebook as a CDF. Would the wrapper cause problems then? If so, I may post a new thread on this issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you would like to change background of `Manipulate` function - this is a way. Note I'll show you most difficult case when you have to go from light to dark colors change - then you have to pay attention to styling of internal graphics too, so everything (like ticks) are visible.

```
st = {FontColor -> GrayLevel[.7]};
Framed[Manipulate[
  Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}, Background -> GrayLevel[.3], 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Orange}, Frame -> True, BaseStyle -> st, 
   ImageMargins -> 7], {{a, 1, "frequency"}, 0, 2, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, Paneled -> False], FrameMargins -> 30, 
 Background -> Black, BaseStyle -> st, RoundingRadius -> 10]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice... can't say I agree with your dark color scheme though...

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Good one! In my case I think I can delete the `BaseStyle`-Options within the `Framed`-environment. Otherwise somehow the corners look very pixeled.

Comment: @John Thanks! Sure, I was just trying to show full scope. Maybe reducing `RoundingRadius` can also help. BTW if you accepted it, you could probably up vote it too? ;-)

Comment: @VitalyKaurov I'm sorry. I didn't pay attention for a sec.

Answer (score 7):

Wrapping `Manipulate` in `Style` and using `DefaultOptions` to set background color of `Panel` and then adjusting `FrameMargins` manually:

```
Panel[Style[Manipulate[
Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}, Background -> None], {a, 0, 2}], 
DefaultOptions -> {Panel -> {Background -> LightBlue}}], 
FrameMargins -> {{-3, -2}, {-2, -3}}]
```

you get

[image]

```
Panel[Style[Manipulate[
Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}, Background -> LightBlue], {a, 0, 2}, 
FrameMargins -> {{-4, -3}, {-2, -2}}], 
DefaultOptions -> {Panel -> {Background -> LightBlue}}], 
      FrameMargins -> {{-3, -2}, {-2, -3}}]
```

gives

[image]

**Update:** Screenshot of free-cdf version deployed as stand-alone and viewed in browser window:

[image]

Comment: uh, this is really hard on the eyes!

Comment: @YvesKlett, hope `LightBlue` is better :)

Comment: @kguler please check Nasser M. Abassis' comment on wrappers around `Manipulate` and demos.

Comment: @John, I am not sure, but I think Nasser's comment refers to the requirements for demonstrations for deploying in `Wolfram Demonstrations` site. I was able to use the code in a new cdf document, deploy it as stand-alone and view it in IE browser without any problem. I posted the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can do it in a `Manipulate` wrapper, but you could technically build your own as such:

```
Panel[Column[{Manipulator[Dynamic[a], {0, 10}], 
   Dynamic[Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}]]}], 
 Background -> LightGreen]
```

[image]

Or...

```
Panel[Column[{Manipulator[Dynamic[a], {0, 10}], 
   Panel[Dynamic[Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}]], 
    Background -> LightGreen]}]]
```

[image]