# I want to change the outer background color of a manipulated plot

Tags: manipulate, color

I downloaded some demonstrations' sources ([for example](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RootsOfComplexNumbers/)) and I want to change their colors. I am only stuck with the white outer background that is around the plot's yellow background.

I would like to see a part of the code where I should put in something like Background->Color.

Comment: I think your question is answered [here.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2261/121)  Would you please try those methods and either confirm the solution or describe how they fail?

Comment: All of my sources are in manipulate which gives more items to be colored, your link shows only plots.
[This one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9826/changing-background-colour-of-a-manipulate-element) is closer to what I am looking for, though they are less interactive plots. In my example the plot reads the position from Locator. I can't see where is the difference that creates this outer white background in my example that is not shown in that thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update: Alternative solution**

Here is a more convenient workaround, using an undocumented `Method` option:

```
Manipulate[Plot[x^2, {x, -2, 2}], {dummy, 0, 1}, 
 Method -> {"ContentAreaBackground" -> LightYellow}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Original answer**

`Manipulate` is designed to put white space around the displayed expression.  Here's a hack workaround:

```
Manipulate[
 Framed[Plot[x^2, {x, -2, 2}], Background -> LightYellow, FrameStyle -> None],
 {dummy, 0, 1}, FrameMargins -> {{-5, -5}, {-3, -5}}]
```

*[Image similar to above, but with a tighter frame]*

You may set `FrameMargins` by trial and error.

Comment: Thanks!

All I needed is to put "FrameMargins -> {{-6, -8}, {-6, -33}}" before Manipulate's ending "]"

[This is how it looks like now.](http://i.imgur.com/eKOZRRc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following helps, using `Framed` and `Paneled->False`

```
Framed[
   Manipulate[
      Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, 5},
           BaseStyle->Orange,PlotStyle->Cyan,Background->GrayLevel[0.2]],
      {a, 1., 5.}, Paneled->False,LabelStyle->{FontSize->14,White}],
   Background->GrayLevel[0.2]]
```