# How to remove the white border in Manipulate?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, output-formatting

Is it possible to remove the default white space around a 3D graphics, inside the Manipulate box ?

Here's a small MWE to show the white border I'm talking about :

```
Manipulate[
SphericalPlot3D[1, {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, t, 2Pi + t},
    Mesh -> {7, 7},
    MaxRecursion -> ControlActive[2, 5],
    PlotRange -> All,
    Boxed -> False,
    Axes -> None,
    SphericalRegion -> True,
    Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"},
    ImageSize -> {400, 400},
    Background -> Black],
{{t, 0, Style["t", 10]}, 0, 2Pi, 0.01}
]
```

[image]

In this case, I would prefer to not have that useless white space between the black background and the manipulate frame.

Comment: `FrameMargins -> None,` makes them smaller

Comment: @JasonB, **FrameMargins -> None** is already much nicer, thanks !  But there's still a small white margin left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this undocumented option suggested by [MichaelE2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25949/9490), we can change the color of the border to the same as the background color of the plot:

```
Manipulate[
 SphericalPlot3D[1, {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, t, 2 Pi + t},
      Mesh -> {7, 7},
      MaxRecursion -> ControlActive[2, 5],
      PlotRange -> All,
      Boxed -> False,
      Axes -> None,
      SphericalRegion -> True,
      Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"},
      ImageSize -> {400, 400},
      Background -> Black],
 {{t, 0, Style["t", 10]}, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01}, 
 Method -> {"ContentAreaBackground" -> Black}]
```

[image]

But this option does not work for version 7, so it is then necessary to set the `FrameMargins` to a small negative value,

```
Manipulate[
   SphericalPlot3D[1, {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, t, 2 Pi + t},
        Mesh -> {7, 7},
        MaxRecursion -> ControlActive[2, 5],
        PlotRange -> All,
        Boxed -> False,
        Axes -> None,
        SphericalRegion -> True,
        Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"},
        ImageSize -> {400, 400},
        Background -> Black],
   {{t, 0, Style["t", 10]}, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01},
   FrameMargins -> #
   ] & /@ {Automatic, None, -5}
```

[image]

Comment: What would be the right negative value to remove all the white space, but not more ?

Comment: For this example, it seems that `FrameMargins -> {{-5, -5}, {-3, -3}}` is just right, but I don't know how universal that is

Comment: This is weird.  The frame isn't regular ?

Comment: @Cham, no, you can see that by setting it `FrameMargins -> -3`.  It might be related to the aspect ratio of the panel.

Comment: Hmm, the **Method -> {"ContentAreaBackground" -> Black}** does nothing on my system.  Not even a warning/error message (version 7).  I still get the white default margin.  There's something fishy in my code.

Comment: It must be a new option, it **is** undocumented even in version 10.  So you are best off using the `FrameMargins` option I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

What about this:

```
 Framed[Manipulate[
  SphericalPlot3D[1, {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, t, 2 Pi + t}, 
   Mesh -> {7, 7}, MaxRecursion -> ControlActive[2, 5], 
   PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, 
   SphericalRegion -> True, Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"}, 
   ImageSize -> {400, 400}, 
   Background -> Black], {{t, 0, Style["t", 10]}, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01}, 
  Paneled -> False], FrameStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.7], Thickness[3]}]
```

yielding this:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Hmm, while it is good to know these options, I don't want to change all the Manipulate frame itself.  I just want to remove the white space around the picture.

Comment: Ah, I understood you incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Manipulate[
 SphericalPlot3D[1, {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, t, 2 Pi + t}, 
  Mesh -> {7, 7}, MaxRecursion -> ControlActive[2, 5], 
  PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, 
  SphericalRegion -> True, Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"}, 
  ImageSize -> {400, 400}, 
  Background -> Black], {{t, 0, Style["t", 10]}, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01},
 Paneled -> False]
```

Comment: **Paneled -> False** remove the whole Manipulate frame, which is not what we want here.